# How can LaTeX suppress page break, when page ends in a list of items?

Tags: latex

There are several ways to suppress page break in \LaTeX, nevertheless, none works for my specific case.

My text contains something like:

```
    Examples
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Example 1.
    \item Example 2.
    ...
    \end{enumerate}
```

How can I avoid "Examples" being in the end of a page while the enumeration starting on the next page? I wouldn't mind, either "Examples" moving in the next page or at least "\item Example 1." staying in the same page with "Examples".